# How to get query output to show in bootstrap modal body

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a search bar for users to enter a query. Upon clicking 'Search', a modal should appear with the query results.

My output from index.php is still not showing in the modal. When I click 'Search', the modal pops up with an empty body. **How do I get my output from index.php to show in the modal's body?**

**index.php**

```html
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action="#">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
   <input type="button" name="search" value="Search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">
   </form>
 </body>

<script>
  $('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault() // do not submit form
      // do get request
     $.get( 'search.php', { q : },function(e){
         // then show the modal first
         $('#mymodal').modal('show');
         // then put the results there
         $('#mymodal:visible .modal-container .modal-body').html(e);
     });
  });
</script>

 <!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="mymodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**search.php**

```html
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);

  include_once('db.php'); //Connect to database
  if(isset($_POST['q'])){
    $q = $_POST['q'];

    //get required columns
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%$q%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //check for query error
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
      $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
    }else{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['yupikWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['englishWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['audio'].'</h2><br>';
        $audio_name = $row['audio'];
        $output .= '<td><audio src="audio/'.$audio_name.'" controls="control">'.$audio_name.'</audio></td>';
      }
    }
    echo $output;
  }else{
    "Please add search parameter";
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `modal-container` != `modal-content`

Comment: also `{ q : }` is not right

Comment: also the code is open SQL injection, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: How is { q : } not right?